# get JSON data from a web-service to make a picture gallery

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

A web-service is available at http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw334/products.php?
limit=12&skip=0

I want to get the data in there into a Javascript array.  I've searched around and I think I should start like this?

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw334/products.php?limit=12&skip=0",
    data: {id:id, name:name,url:url},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: ??
    }
});
```

How should I continue to get this data from the .php file into a Javascript array?

Comment: You're asking about basic jQuery usage here... please read the jQuery docs, they'll provide all the information about ajax requests and success callbacks that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 product = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw334/products.php?limit=12&skip=0",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.products).each(function(i, products){
            product[products.id] = products.name;
        });
        console.log(product);
    }
});
```